# Pass a selected DatePicker to another View

Tags: xcode, swiftui, datepicker

I have a DatePicker in mi ContentView.

The App im working for, requires that all the other views, has the same DatePicker, with the exact Date selected in the ContentView page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a Binding variable?

Comment: I had use a Binding variable before with Text, but for some reason with the Date is different.

Comment: with `Date` is no different. I can show you a quick demo, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes I am please :)

Comment: That one worked for me. :) really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the demo code that shows how to pass a `Date` variable to other views using binding.
If you not not require the other views to change the date,
then use `@State var sameDate: Date` instead of `@Binding var sameDate: Date`.

You can also achieve the same with an single `ObservableObject` and passing it using `@EnvironmentObject`, see EDIT-1.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var birthDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (spacing: 80) {
                DatePicker(selection: $birthDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("Select a date")
                }.padding(.top, 50)
                NavigationLink("Next view", destination: NextView1(sameDate: $birthDate))
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct NextView1: View {
    @Binding var sameDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 80) {
            DatePicker(selection: $sameDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Next view-1 date")
            }.padding(.top, 50)
            NavigationLink("Next view", destination: NextView2(sameDate: $sameDate))
        }
    }
}

struct NextView2: View {
    @Binding var sameDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker(selection: $sameDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text("Next view-2 date")
        }.padding(.top, 50)
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: using a `ObservableObject`.

```
class DateManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var birthDate = Date()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dateManager = DateManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (spacing: 80) {
                DatePicker(selection: $dateManager.birthDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("Select a date")
                }.padding(.top, 50)
                NavigationLink("Next view 1", destination: NextView1())
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .environmentObject(dateManager)
    }
}

struct NextView1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dateManager: DateManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 80) {
            DatePicker(selection: $dateManager.birthDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Next view-1 date")
            }.padding(.top, 50)
            NavigationLink("Next view 2", destination: NextView2())
        }
    }
}

struct NextView2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dateManager: DateManager
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker(selection: $dateManager.birthDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text("Next view-2 date")
        }.padding(.top, 50)
    }
}
```